# Why can a Try[Try[Unit]] value be assigned to Try[Unit]?

Tags: scala, error-handling

I've just came across a very weird behavior. Here's the code:

```
// So far everything's fine
val x: Try[Try[Unit]] = Try(Try{})
x: scala.util.Try[scala.util.Try[Unit]] = Success(Success(()))

// Compilation error should happen here
val x: Try[Unit] = Try(Try{})
// Wuut ?
x: scala.util.Try[Unit] = Success(())
```

I was expecting a compilation error here, as (as far as I know) a `Try[Try[Unit]]` should not be assignable to a `Try[Unit]`, but in this case it seems that a `Try{}` is automatically converted to a `Unit` (`()`). How is that possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any type can be adapted to `Unit` in the right context by simply dropping the value. In this case, the expression is parsed like this:

```
val x: Try[Unit] = Try {
  Try {}
  () // adapting the result to Unit
}
```

You can make the scala compiler issue warnings for such cases by passing `-Ywarn-value-discard`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? Anything can be `Unit`: `val a: Unit = 2`.

This is the same as when you write:

```
def test: Unit = {
  Try{}
}
```

So you should think of it as wrapping `Try` in `{}` and losing the result